# Read files with stdlib.h C++

Tags: c++, std, flags, dev-c++

I have some problems with reading files with C++ using stdlib.h header. Please correct the mistakes from my syntax. The compiler said 'FILE has no member named buffer, curp, fd, and flags'  What does that mean?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    FILE *fp;

    if ((fp = fopen("text.txt", "w"))==NULL){
        printf("error!");
        exit(1);
    }

    fputs("ABCDE\n", fp);
    printf("file address : %p\n", fp->buffer);
    printf("file size : %d byte \n", fp->bsize);
    printf("file position : %p\n", fp->curp);
    printf("file contents : ");

    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++){
        printf("%c", *(fp->buffer+i));
    }

    printf("\n");
    printf("file identity is unknown : %d\n", fp->fd);
    printf("file status : \n");

    if ((fp->flags & 1)==1) printf ("readonly\n");
    if ((fp->flags & 2)==2) printf ("writeonly\n");
    if ((fp->flags & 3)==3) printf ("read/write\n");
    if ((fp->flags & 8)==8) printf ("file line\n");
    if ((fp->flags & 16)==16) printf ("error\n");
    if ((fp->flags & 32)==32) printf ("end of the file\n");
    if ((fp->flags & 64)==64) printf ("binary file\n"); else printf ("file text\n");
    if ((fp->flags & 128)==128) printf ("data from file\n");
    if ((fp->flags & 256)==256) printf ("data from file\n");
    if ((fp->flags & 512)==512) printf ("file is in the terminal\n"); else  printf("file is in the disk");

    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: Error messages verbatim please!

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: _"'FILE has no member named ...'"_ Provide the full verbatim text please! (in your question)

Comment: It has been added.

Comment: [`FILE`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io`) doesn't have that member. At least not defined by standards.

Comment: So what i have to do?

Comment: Check [`ftell()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/ftell)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FILE` is an opaque type; the C standard doesn't define its fields, so they can vary between implementations.  Your program expects the `FILE` type to have fields with certain names, but your system doesn't actually define it that way.

Don't rely on `FILE` having specific fields, and don't dereference a `FILE*` to try to access those fields.  Instead, use the functions provided by the C standard library, such as `fread` to read contents and `ftell` to get the current position.  These functions take a `FILE*` parameter and access its contents in whatever way is correct for the system where the program is running.